# Gratis Log visualization tools

Tags: gratis, ubuntu, logs, log-analysis, system-monitor

**First, let me explain what I mean by log visualization tools.**

I mean something that has a decent GUI that looks semi-impressive (lots of charts/graphs, maybe a pie chart or two).  Here's an example of what I mean

[image: GUI with charts/graphs + pie charts]

This picture was taken from [this](https://michael.bouvy.net/blog/en/2013/11/19/collect-visualize-your-logs-logstash-elasticsearch-redis-kibana/) tutorial, and it looks awesome.

**Another** example would be [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)

[image: Logstash UI]

---

**"Why is this person looking for something that looks cool instead caring more about features and data collection?"**

That's a fantastic question!  Some of you may work in IT, DevOps, or something similar.  For better or worse management tends to care more about data that looks cool than data that is useful.

I recently starting using [Logstalgia](http://logstalgia.io/), and nothing has gotten me more praise than this one thing.  This one thing that gives you very little data, but looks amazing.  Now, I did actually find something on the network that I didn't expect while looking at logstalgia, so it's by no means useless, but it is definitely more for looks.

---

**To elaborate on my actual question**

What tools do you use, that give you some useful data, but keep in mind the priority that form is more important than function?

---

**Technical Details**

You solution doesn't necessarily have to meet my specific environment, but here it is just for reference.

Ubuntu 14.04 Desktop

All my log files are already on a single syslog server.

The types of files I have are;

Nginx

Apache

Syslog

but, as stated above, my specific requirements shouldn't really sway your answer too much, as this is a general question on what tools are available that are cool looking and have some functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had this question. After doing a lot of research and PoC work, our team found no better option than ELK stack.  The same one which you have mentioned. It has lot of additional features.

This is a great tool if you want open source.